# Can't scroll the screen to the center of a div after animating it's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

#### The way the website is suposed to work:

- Multiple "stripes", each with it's own picture, displayed horizontally.
- The window scrolls to the sides to show more
- When you click on a stripe, it expands to a bigger width and the screen should scroll to center that big stripe.

The problem I'm having is that the scroll to center the screen isn't working properly. I'm guessing it's because of the fact that the div's width is animated so the calculations don't get the correct value.

You can view what I have so far here: http://sandbox.stamina.pt/shiny-people/

The JS I'm using is:

```
$(".site-content .item").toggle(function() {
    $(this).addClass('open');
    if(clicked != $(this))
    {
        // this bit detects if the click was on a different slice and closes the old open one.
        if($(clicked).hasClass('page'))
        {
            $(clicked).animate({
                'width' : '40%',
            }, 300);
        }
        else {
            $(clicked).animate({
                'width' : '17%',
            }, 300);
        }
    }
    $(this).animate({
        'width': '68%',
    }, 300);
    var elWidth = $(this).width();
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var elOffset = $(this).offset();

    $('.content-area').animate({"scrollLeft": (elOffset.left + (elWidth/2) - (viewportWidth/2)) }, 1500);
    clicked = $(this);
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    if($(this).hasClass('page'))
    {
        $(this).animate({
            'width': '40%',
        }, 300);    
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).animate({
            'width': '17%',
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

The bits with the ".page" thing is because among those stripes there will be a couple of different, bigger sized blocks that will behave the same except they'll be a bit bigger.

Any idea on how I can make this work?

Cheers!

Comment: i guess because animate() works async in some way, you didn't have accurate width. Try to put code inside last animate complete callback   `$(this).animate({
        'width': '68%',
    }, 300,function(){...});`  Or maybe, just: `var elWidth = $(this).parent().width() * 68 / 100;`

Comment: Okay, that seems to have improved it! On the items to the right it still needs to slide a bit more, but if the item is to the left it scrolls way too much...